# CloudKit Console: JSON Web Token Validator shows Unrecognizable claims found (Token Generated with Python)

Tags: python, ios, jwt, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

Hello guys I am getting this error `Unrecognizable claims found` when trying to validate my JWT Token for push notifications.

[image]

I don't understand what it means. Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue?

I am using python, and using the `time` module to generate the epoch. I guess, this is where the issue is coming from, but I am not sure.

```
import time
epoch = time.time()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of "typ" header in JWT token. If you remove it, the error disappears.